# Get text for error code returned by Poco?

Tags: c++, poco

I have an App with a Poco module for internet connection to support users with legacy XP and Vista OS connecting with TLS1.2. There is a connection problem that returns a Poco error code but I don't know what that means. Here is part of the logging output:

```
poco_connection::end_receiving_response_body entered
poco_connection::close entered
poco_session::destroy_connection entered
poco_connection::end_transaction entered (code 0x00280166, hresult 0x00000000, closing: FALSE)
--------- 043d7450 (Closing request)
poco_connection::transaction_notify entered (code 0x00280166, hresult 0x00000000): Status: 3
Poco Communication Failed: code 0x00280166, hresult 0x00000000
poco_connection::~poco_connection entered
```

A little research shows there is a class Poco::Error that includes a method

static std::string getMessage(
    int errorCode
);

which returns a text string for errors.  Unfortunately I don't have source for the Poco module and so I can't add that translation call.

Since Poco is an open source project, can anyone point me to a code location where I can look up the mapping of Poco errors?  Specifically error code 0x00280166

Answer (score 0):

Seems I got lucky with a bit of googling

https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/Error.cpp

But I don't think you're in luck, the code just assumes the error code is a windows system error code. And when I google 0x00280166 this page is the only hit.